# Nginx subdomain configuration not working

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to add a subdomain to my nginx server, and can't seem to get it working.  Here's the config file for my primary server:

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.kevin-whitaker.net;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://kevin-whitaker.net permanent;
           }

server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  kevin-whitaker.net;

            access_log /home/admin/public_html/kevin-whitaker.net/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/admin/public_html/kevin-whitaker.net/log/error.log;

            root   /home/admin/public_html/kevin-whitaker.net/public/;
            index  index.html;

            location / {
                          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                          proxy_redirect false;

                          if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                          }

                          if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                          }

            }

}
```

And for the subdomain:

```
server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  www.pci.kevin-whitaker.net;
            rewrite ^/(.*) http://pci.kevin-whitaker.net permanent;
           }

server {
            listen   80;
            server_name  pci.kevin-whitaker.net;

            access_log /home/admin/public_html/pci.kevin-whitaker.net/log/access.log;
            error_log /home/admin/public_html/pci.kevin-whitaker.net/log/error.log;

            root   /home/admin/public_html/pci.kevin-whitaker.net/public/;
            index  index.html;

            location / {
                          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                          proxy_redirect false;

                          if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
                          }

                          if (-f $request_filename.html) {
                                           rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
                          }

            }

}
```

The primary domain (kevin-whitaker.net) functions like it should.  However, the subdomain is unresolved when I try to browse to or ping it.  Is there some other step I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the domain names used above are the ones you are talking about then your subdomain may not be working because there is no DNS entry for them. Do a dig and look for answer section in the reply.

`dig kevin-whitaker.net` has a proper answer section where as `dig pci.kevin-whitaker.net` is missing the answer section. Just put the DNS entries and you would be good to go.